# Ampleness of sheaf on qcqs scheme is local property?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a quasi-compact, quasi-separated scheme and let $\mathcal{L}$ be an invertible $\mathcal{O}_X$-module.

Let $X = \bigcup _{a \in A} V_a$ be a finite open (possibly affine) covering.

**Q.** If each $\mathcal{L}|_{V_a}$ is ample, then $\mathcal{L}$ is ample?

**EDIT** : As Ariyan Javanpeykar answered, this question is false in general. But how about the case that each $V_a$ is pairwise disjoint?

**O.K.** I will try to show that "if $X= U \cup V$ is a scheme which is disjoint union of two open subscheme such that each $\mathcal{L}|_U$ and $\mathcal{L}|_V$is ample, then $\mathcal{L}$ is ample." The case '$A$ is finite (above question)' is similar.

By the https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01PR (definition of the ampleness), to show that $\mathcal{L}$ is ample, it suffices to show that for every $x \in X$, there exists an $n\ge 1$ and $s \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{L}^n)$ such that $x \in X_s := \{x\in X | s_x \notin \mathbb{m}_x\mathcal{L}^n_x \}$ is affine.

Fix $x\in X= U \biguplus V$.  We may assume that $x\in U$. Pick another $x'\in V$. Since each $\mathcal{L}|_U$ , $\mathcal{L}|_V$ is ample, by the definition above, there exists $m, m' \ge 1$ and $s' \in \Gamma(U,\mathcal{L}^m)$, $s''\in \Gamma(V,\mathcal{L}^{m'})$ such that $x\in U_{s'}$ is affine and $x'\in V_{s''}$ is affine.

Now, set $s \in \Gamma(X, \mathcal{L}^{mm'})$ to be $s|_U = (s')^{\otimes m'}$ and $s|_V = (s'')^{\otimes m}$. ( By the definition of tensor product  of section, c.f. Gortz's Algebraic Geometry book p.175. And, this existence of lifting is possible by the disjointness of $U$ and $V$ and the sheaf axiom ! ).

Now we show that $X_s = U_{s'} \biguplus V_{s''}$. Then since $x\in U_{s'} \subseteq X_s$ and the disjoint union of affine schemes is also affine, we are done.

$\because$ $X_s = U_{s'} \biguplus V_{s''}$ :

- $\supseteq $ : maybe true (?).
- $\subseteq $ : Let $x\in X_s$. Then $s_x \notin \mathbb{m}_x\mathcal{L}^{mm^{'}}_x$.

Case 1) $x\in U$ : Note that since $(s|_U)_{x} = s_x$,
$ x\in U_{(s|_U)} = U_{(s')^{\otimes m'}} = U_{s'} $

Case 2) $x\in V$ : Since $(s|_V)_x =s_x$, $x\in V_{(s|_V)} = V_{(s'')^{\otimes m}} = V_{s''}$.

( The final equalities are true by the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, Remark 13.46-(3), or https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01PR )

Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Let $X=\mathbb{P}^1$. Let $X = U\cap V$ be the usual open affine covering by copies of $\mathbb{A}^1$. Take $L=\mathcal{O}_X$.

Note that $\mathcal{O}_U = (\mathcal{O}_X)|_U$ is ample on $U$. Similarly $\mathcal{O}_V$ is ample on $V$.

But $L$ is not ample.

Comment: O.K. I've been thinking about this topic for quite some time. Thanks.

Comment: Uhm. Can I ask further? How about the case that each $V_a$ is pairwise disjoint? :)